# .Net equivalent of VB6's IsObject for WMI queries

Tags: .net, vb.net, wmi

I'm sure I'm not the first to encounter this. Searching for things like "VB.Net isobject" returns nothing, so the answer is probably too obvious to be worth posting.

My code:

```
Dim colItems As Object
colItems = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery(strQuery)

Dim objItem As Object
For Each objItem In colItems
    If isObject(objItem) Then
        If objItem.StatusCode = 0 Then
            IsOnline = True
            colItems = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The error:

```
'IsObject' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I *think* what I need is

```
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
```

Is that correct?

Comment: You should be able to use the [`IsNot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) operator. `If objItem IsNot Nothing Then`

Comment: or `If objItem IsNot Nothing Then` of you prefer the code to not look like Yoda wrote it.  Generally, you should avoid `As Object` to begin with - that collection returned has specific types in it: `For Each item As ManagementObject In ms.Get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, `IsObject()` is decidedly less useful in .NET, but given the context, it looks like you want to test for `Nothing` / null.  In which case these will work

```
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then ...
' or
If objItem IsNot Nothing Then ...
```

---

More important is that the code will not compile under `Option Strict`:

```
Dim colItems As Object
colItems = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery(strQuery)
```

`Object` doesnt not have a `ExecQuery` method, so that code requires late binding; the same for `objItem.StatusCode`.

The code generally looks like maybe it originated from a script.  Using the COM interface and dealing with `Object` and late binding is not needed when there is a nice NET wrapper for `WMI`.  I dont know what you were querying for, this will get the serial number of the BIOS:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Management

Public Class WMI
    Friend Shared Function ExecWMIQuery(wmiclass As String, queryItem As String) As String

    Dim retVal As String = ""
    Dim query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", queryItem, wmiclass)

    Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        For Each item As ManagementObject In searcher.Get

            Dim p = item.Properties(queryItem)
            If (p IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (p.Value IsNot Nothing) Then
                retVal = p.Value.ToString
                ' should be nothing else...
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
    End Using
    Return retVal
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
    Dim mySerial = WMI.ExecWMIQuery("Win32_Bios", "SerialNumber")
    Console.WriteLine(mySerial)
```

I tend to be careful with WMI since you are often at the mercy of whatever the manufacturer chose to include or omit, so there are checks for `Nothing` and so forth.

The larger point is that `System.Management` exposes typed objects and collections so that you do not have to declare everything `As Object` and can use `Option Strict` to prevent much worse things from happening.

See also:

- [ManagementObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [WMI Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554(v=vs.85).aspx) ... the starting point for all the classes and what they provide.

Comment: It is indeed a very old VBScript function that queried the StatusCode of the Win32_PingStatus class to determine if a remote host was online (fastest test I know of). I wanted to avoid early binding, but it appears VB.nEt really likes early binding. While both yours and @Heinzi's answers answered my question, you goes above and beyond by providing examples.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *direct* equivalent. `IsObject` was used in VB6 (and [is used in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251535.aspx)) to determine whether a `Variant` contains an object reference.

Since `Object` is the VB.NET successor to VB6's `Variant` and even the built-in primitive types (Integer, String, etc.) derive from `Object`, `IsObject` is kind of pointless in VB.NET.

The closest equivalent might be [IsReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isreference(v=vs.110).aspx).